# Need an equation to fit this exponential curve

Tags: exponential-function, extrapolation, curves

I need a curve that grows exponentially. Only 2 data points are important:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
```

After that, I just need to be able to play with how much the graph curves upwards. y=x^2 is the simplest curve that satisfies this, but it jumps up too high for me in the beginning (y=4 when x=2, I would want y to equal something like 2.5) and it doesn't curve up enough as x gets above 8 or so.

Comment: $x^2$ is polynomial not exponential!

Comment: @NilsZiehn - ok, I don't know the exact definitions of the terminology. Should the title be changed to ".. fit this exponential/polynomial curve"?

Comment: Maybe you should just leave it out, because it is misleading (exponential is something like $e^x$ ) and instead just maybe give some more information how it should look. For instance this might be a good one for you: $5\cdot 1.2^x-5$

Comment: Maybe even $2.5\cdot 1.4^x-2.5$

Comment: @NilsZiehn - you should make this an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  $$2.5\cdot 1.4^x−2.5$$

But you could also look at $$5\cdot 1.2^x−5$$

Comment: I used 1.3 for the base and 10/3 for the multiplier but this formula worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

What about $y = 2^x/2$? The first five coordinates are {{0,0),(2,2),(3,4),(4,8)}.? You can't have an exponential function just "not curve up" until 8 or so.

Comment: ofcourse you can: $2.5\cdot 1.4^x−2.5$ for instance!

Comment: At x=5, that function will equal 10.945. But yes, I concede that your function does have a smaller slope.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is with it being above 11 at 5? at01 asked for a function that rises up after passing 2

Comment: first 5 coords are (0, 1/2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4)